# How to use Fiddler to monitor traffic between HTTPS Soap Service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, https, fiddler

I have a Java based soap service which sends web service request to third party service and expects synchronous response. Request is `HTTPS` and not `HTTP` (that's why I cannot use TCPMon). I've never used `Fiddler` before, only `TCPMon` to monitor traffic but TCPMon doesn't work for HTTPS request. Researched online and found that Fiddler support HTTPS traffic monitoring but am having hard time to configure Fiddler.

Can someone please explain or direct me a link 
1. How to configure Fiddler to forward my request to third party service
2. How to configure my java client.

I read this [documentation](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureJavaApp) but it is not clear where to configure Fiddler so that request is forwarded to target host and port.

**EDIT:** The other question do not state (as I mentioned above also) where to specify in Fiddler the target host name and port

Comment: As for configuring Fiddler itself, just turn on the Decrypt HTTPS Traffic option: http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS

Comment: You don't; you just tell your Java application to use it as a proxy. It will communicate the target to the proxy. See http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureJavaApp